# Is $F(f)=\int_{a}^{b}\phi(f(t))dt$a differentiable function?

Tags: analysis

Let $E=C[a,b]$ the Banach space of functions which are continuous from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, with the norm of max (or sup). Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ twice continuously differentiable. Study if $F:C[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ define by $$F(f)=\int_{a}^{b}\phi(f(t))dt$$ is differentiable.

**My doubt:** I'm not familiar with the proof by definition in this case. 
Can someone explain how to do this problem? Thanks

Comment: What you want to show is that there exists a linear $D_F \colon C(a,b)\to \mathbb R$ such that $$F(f+h)-F(f)= D_F(h) + \text o (h)\qquad h\to 0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you can use the fact that $$\phi (f+h)-\phi(f)-\phi ' (f) h=\frac{1}{2}\phi ''(f+\tau h)h^2,$$ for some $\tau \in (0,1)$.

---

The definition I'm using is the one of [Frechèt derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative). Here's the complete solution of the exercise.

Fix $f\in C(a,b)$. For $h\in C(a,b)$ we have: $$\phi (f(t)+h (t))-\phi (f(t))=\phi '(f(t))h(t)+\frac{1}{2} \phi ''(f(t)+\tau h(t))h^2(t)$$ for some $\tau \in (0,1)$. (This follows from a basic theorem of real analysis, since $\phi$ is assumed to be twice differentiable).
So: $$F(f+h)-F(f)=\int [\phi '(f(t))h(t)+\frac{1}{2} \phi ''(f(t)+\tau h(t))h^2(t) ]\text d t$$
If we define $$D_F(f;h)=\int \phi '(f(t))h(t)\text d t,$$
we see that $D_F$ is a linear function of the variation $h$ and that $$F(f+h)-F(f)-D_F(f;h)=\int \dfrac{1}{2}\phi ''(f(t)+\tau h(t))h^2(t)\text d t.$$
It remains to prove that the second part is $o(h)$ (in fact it is $O(h^2)$).
We have: $$|\int \cdots |\leq \int |\cdots | \leq \max [\frac{|h^2|}{2}]\int |\phi''(f(t)+\tau h(t))|\text d t=\frac{||h^2||}{2} \int |\phi''(f(t)+\tau h(t))|\text d t.$$
So if we can prove that the last integral isbounded by some constant $A$ (for small $h$'s) we are done. To do this, we assume that $\phi '' $ is continuous in a compact set $K$ containing $f([a,b])$ in its interior. If we choose $h$ small enough, we have $f(t)+\tau h(t)\in K$ for all $t\in [a,b]$. But $|\phi''|$, being continuous, takes a maximum $M$ in $K$, so we can bound the integral with $M (b-a)$.

---

There is no general rule to differentiate a functional (as far as I know). The method is: look at the difference of $F(f+h)-F(f)$ and see if you can write it as $\text {Linear part in $h$} + O(h^2)$.

Comment: Excuse the insistence, but i'm little worried (or terrified) with the definition. Because i don't know how to find $D_F$. Please Can you write more explicit is to learn!! I'm studying for my Analysis test.

Comment: No problem, look at the updated answer ;-)

Comment: Really, really thanks!!!